# Are there two groups $G_1 , G_2 $ of orders $7$ and $8$ respectively & a morphism $f: G_1 \to G_2 $ such that $|\operatorname{Im}(f)| = 4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, morphism

Is is possible to find two groups $G_1, G_2 $ of orders $7$ and $8$ respectively & a morphism $f: G_1 \to G_2$ such that $|\operatorname{Im}(f)| = 4$ ?

Comment: It is usually considered inappropriate to phrase questions posted here in language suitable for assigning homework, especially when they are phrased in a way that makes it look as if the poster hasn't thought about the question.  That is probably the reason for the down-votes here.  People who do that with a newbie's posting ought to post a comment here explaining that, but usually they don't. $\qquad$

Comment: I have given it some thought but after I got the notation down on the page I didn't get very far. I posted the question as I read it hoping that it'd be at its clearest. Abstract Algebra is where I fall apart so I honestly need as much help as one can give me.

Comment: To clarify: I meant that people who down-vote a posting for that reason ought to say so in a comment, not that people who post such things ought to.  The latter should put their initial thoughts in the question itself. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Since $G_1/\ker(f) \cong \operatorname{Im}(f)$ per the isomorphism theorem, we have $|G_1/\ker(f)| = |G_1|/|\ker(f)| = |\operatorname{Im}(f)|$.  Is this possible?

In greater generality, notice that when $|G| = p$ is prime, any homomorphism $\phi:G \rightarrow G'$ is either trivial or an isomorphism since $|\ker(\phi)| = 1 \text{ or } p$.